# How to explain the result of ANCOVA and linear regression

Tags: r, static, regression, linear-regression, ancova

Currently I am learning ANCOVA, but I'm confused with the result.

I created a linear regression model using `mtcars` like this:

```
summary(lm(qsec ~ wt+factor(am), data = mtcars))
```

The output is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = qsec ~ wt + factor(am), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6898 -1.3063  0.0167  1.1398  3.9917 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  22.5990     1.5596  14.490 8.17e-15 ***
wt           -1.1716     0.4025  -2.911  0.00685 ** 
factor(am)1  -2.4141     0.7892  -3.059  0.00474 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.582 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.267, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2165 
F-statistic: 5.283 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 0.01106
```

As you see, the p value of `wt` showed 0.00685, which meaned a strong linear correlation between `wt` and `qsec`, as well as `am`.

But when I ran `aov` code:

```
summary(aov(qsec ~ wt+factor(am), data = mtcars))
```

With the output:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
wt           1   3.02   3.022   1.208 0.28081   
factor(am)   1  23.41  23.413   9.358 0.00474 **
Residuals   29  72.55   2.502                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

It seems like there was no effect from `wt` on `qsec`.

Does it mean that a strong linear correlation between `wt` and `qsec` could be confirmed but there is no great effect from `wt` on `qsec`?
Is my explanation appropriate?

Comment: Could this answer here help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55571/difference-in-reported-p-values-between-lm-and-aov-in-r#:~:text=summary%20%28aov%29%20uses%20so%20called%20Type%20I%20%28sequential%29,converts%20the%20RHS%20of%20the%20formula%20to%20factors%29.

Comment: @Archeologist Thanks for your comment! I think this answer is very informative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop the `factor` since `am` only has two values so making it a factor will not have any effect on the results.

Now regarding the tests to get the p values they are different. For `lm` the `wt` p value is based on the comparison of these two models

```
qsec ~ am
qsec ~ wt + am
```

so we have

```
anova(lm(qsec ~ am, mtcars), lm(qsec ~ mt + am, mtcars))
## Model 1: qsec ~ am
## Model 2: qsec ~ wt + am
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
## 1     30 93.758                                
## 2     29 72.554  1    21.204 8.4753 0.006854 ** <-- 0.00685

summary(lm(qsec ~ wt + am, mtcars))
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  22.5990     1.5596  14.490 8.17e-15 ***
## wt           -1.1716     0.4025  -2.911  0.00685 ** <-- 0.00685
## am           -2.4141     0.7892  -3.059  0.00474 **
```

whereas `aov` is really meant for balanced designs where the terms are orthogonal and if not, as here, then it conceptually orthogonalizes them sequentially so in that case the comparison is effectively between these two models

```
qsec ~ r.am
qsec ~ r.wt + r.am
```

where r.wt is the portion of `wt` orthogonal to the intercept and r.am is the portion of `am` orthogonal to `wt` and the intercept so we have

```
r.wt <- resid(lm(wt ~ 1, mtcars))
r.am <- resid(lm(am ~ wt, mtcars))

anova(lm(qsec ~ r.am, mtcars), lm(qsec ~ r.wt + r.am, mtcars))
## Model 1: qsec ~ r.am
## Model 2: qsec ~ r.wt + r.am
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     30 75.576                           
## 2     29 72.554  1    3.0217 1.2078 0.2808 <------- 0.2808

summary(aov(qsec ~ wt + am, mtcars))
##             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
## wt           1   3.02   3.022   1.208 0.28081 <------- 0.28081
## am           1  23.41  23.413   9.358 0.00474 **
## Residuals   29  72.55   2.502
```

It would also be possible to demonstrate this by performing Gram Schmidt on the `cbind(1, wt, am)` model matrix to make the columns orthogonal.  The pracma package has a Gram Schmidt routine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which gave me a better understanding of ancova as a beginner!
Your answer succinctly and clearly demonstrates how the two methods handle the data differently. So I can understand that the `wt` p-value obtained by the linear regression approach indicates that there is indeed a correlation between `wt` and `qsec`, but the difference of effect on `qsec` between `wt` of `am0` and `wt` of `am1` is not significant?

Comment: Adding `wt` to the `qsec ~ am` model improves the the fit significantly but adding `r.wt` to `qsec ~ r.am` does not.  It is not saying anything about correlation.  `cor(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$wt)` equals `cor(mtcars$qsec, r.wt)` .

Comment: Thank you very much for your addition! Your answer cleared up all my questions!